# ERROR 1045 (28000) [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure

Tags: mysql, sql

When I write in the prompt

```
mysql -u root -p;
```

the prompt throw back this:

`mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

How i can solve this? Thank you bros!

Comment: Just remove the semicolon, so your command should be `mysql -u root -p` and then press enter...

Answer (score 1):

Just enter `mysql -u root -p` and hit `Enter` which will prompt you enter the password which will be masked and won't display in screen